# How to divide a number into multiple unequal parts in python?

Tags: python, list, split

I have a `list` with multiple numbers in it:

```
num_list = ['A',3452,3487,6534,4521]
```

The `list` has 1st element as a `string` that serve as an identifier.

Now what I want to do is take each `number` in the `list`, **divide it into four parts in - 18%,22%,24% and 36%**, and then form a new list which has 1st element as the string in previous list followed by the 4 divided parts of each number of previous list. So the output should be something like:

```
new_list = ['A',part1 of num1,part2 of num1,part3 of num1,part4 of num1,part1 of num2,part2 of num2,part3 of num2,part4 of num2......]
```

How can I do this in python?

Comment: `new_list = [num_list[0]]; new_list.append(num_list[1] * 0.18); new_list.append(num_list[1] * 0.22); ...`

Comment: What have you done so far ? Can you provide a code ?

Comment: Strongly disagree with the 'too broad' closing votes. This is a very specific question, and is clearly stated.

Comment: @CraigOtis: The question does not provide any background research to solve the problem. So `too broad` flag is applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve it with a *list comprehension*:

```
>>> num_list = ['A', 3452, 3487, 6534, 4521]
>>> percents = [0.18, 0.22, 0.24, 0.36]
>>> [num_list[0]] + [item * percent for item in num_list[1:] for percent in percents]
['A', 621.36, 759.44, 828.48, 1242.72, 627.66, 767.14, 836.88, 1255.32, 1176.12, 1437.48, 1568.1599999999999, 2352.24, 813.78, 994.62, 1085.04, 1627.56]
      # --------- num1 ------------ #  # --------- num2 ------------ #  # ------------------ num3 ----------------- #  # --------- num4 ------------- #
```